# Упорядочивание записей в таблице данных

Tags: mysql

В книге написано что записи в таблицах неупорядочены . То есть нет первой, второй, третьей записи. 
Решил я это протестировать на простом примере :

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE one(id int,status int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.48 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO one VALUES(1,1),(2,2),(2,8),(5,5),(6,6);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM one LIMIT 1;
+------+--------+
| id   | status |
+------+--------+
|    1 |      1 |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Сколько не повторять последний запрос результатом будет та самая строка .

Comment: Вопрос то в чём? )

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обязательно ли делать ORDER BY для упорядоченных данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700947/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-order-by-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

вы на таком тесте ничего не увидите. Да, он будет возвращать одну и ту же запись, специально выбирать с диска другую запись в следующий раз он не начнет.

Не упорядоченность выражается в том, что вы не можете предсказать, какая именно запись будет первой на диске. При последовательной вставке та, что первой вставлена, та и окажется первой в блоке данных. Но если с таблицей идет интенсивная работа, записи добавляются, редактируются, удаляются, то через какое то время может оказаться, что первая вставленная запись была удалена, место в блоке освободилось на столько, что СУБД решила его использовать и положила на это место какую нибудь новую запись. В итоге ваш запрос выдаст эту новую запись как первую.

```
INSERT INTO one VALUES(1,1),(2,2),(2,8),(5,5),(6,6);
select * from one limit 1;

Результат: 1,1

delete from one where id<3;
select * from one limit 1;

Результат: 5,5

insert into one values(10,10);
select * from one limit 1;

Результат: 10,10
```

Результат может отличатся в зависимости от engine таблицы, наличия индексов и других условий. Гарантировать, что вышеприведенный тест будет выполняться именно так -  невозможно.

По этой причине, в случае если нужно получить строго упорядоченный набор данных, *необходимо* явно указывать порядок сортировки с помощью предложения `ORDER BY`

Comment: В [том вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700947/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-order-by-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) сам вопрос сформулирован гораздо лучше, может перенесёте свой ответ туда?

Comment: @Darth Может тогда перенести вопрос сюда ? Этот как бы более ранний и на него уже где то могут ссылаться

Comment: 51 просмотр за 1,5 года - врядли сюда кто-то ссылается.