# Обязательно ли делать ORDER BY для упорядоченных данных

Tags: mysql, sql

К примеру есть таблица `users` с одним столбцом `id`

```
id |
----
1
2
3
4
```

Я делаю элементарный SELECT

```
SELECT id FROM users
```

и получаю данные `1, 2, 3, 4` в том порядке в котором они пронумерованы.

Собственно вопрос: всегда ли MySQL гарантирует что данные будут получены именно в том порядке в котором они пронумерованы? Т. е. возможен ли случай когда например результат будет такой: `1, 3, 2, 4`?
Или все же лучше использовать явную сортировку?

SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id

Comment: Нет, он этого не гарантирует. записи отдаются в том порядке, как лежат на диске. если вы удалите несколько первых записей и добавите новые, хоть у них будут id из конца в выборке они скорее всего окажутся первыми

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам необходимо получить упорядоченный набор, всегда используйте сортировку. 
Например, если вставлять строки не по порядку, например так:

```
id |
----
1
4
2
3
```

то без сортировки вы их в таком виде и получите.

Часто вы будите получать в результате запроса строки в порядке вставки, но даже этого СУБД вам не гарантирует.
По этому, **всегда когда вам нужен упорядоченный набор данных, указывайте сортировку явно**.